# HTML: Scrolling become slow using div scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, worker, vertical-scrolling

I am currently dealing with a file upload using html and javascript. I have div tag without scroll and able to show the images and easily scroll down using the browser scroll bar. Now i have to change the div tag to have a scroll bar but when I did that, the interface started to unresponsive when loading the images.

Each image will be loaded one by one after each upload. Before uploading it, I resized and orientated the image before sending. I tried to use worker thread but it can't handle dom etc.

Is there other way of improving the speed...

The code below get the exif from an image and do a orientation to the image

```
var loadingMetaImage = function (f, index, callback) {
        loadImage.parseMetaData(
        f,
        function (data) {
        if (data.exif)
        options = { canvas: true, orientation: data.exif.get('Orientation') };
        else
        options = { canvas: true };

        loadImage(
        f,
        function (img) {
        callback(img.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0));
        },
        options);
        });
        };
```

Code which calling the code above and have it resized (resize in steps to achieve a better quality)

```
 loadingMetaImage(file.unprocessed, file.index, function (data) {
                        self.imageResize(data, function (result) {
                        self.files[file.index].datas = data;
                        uploadFile(file.index, result, file.name, file.realName, file.hasReader);
                        });
                        });
```

Comment: Is it possible for us to see this? Can you show the code running somewhere?

Comment: Simon, what browsers are you targeting? Years ago, when using IE 6, I found that the performance of a scrolling `div` was pretty bad when it has a lot of content. At that time, the solution we settled on was to render the content in an `iframe` instead. It wasn't an ideal solution, of course, but the performance was much, much better.

Comment: I am using chrome but i think is because of the resizing the image and doing the orientation cause the browser unresponsive... Compare with browser scroll bar, the div scroll bar much more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroll-div{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 60%;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 40%;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll-div'>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
    Some text <br><br>
</div>
<p>
The code there is:
<br><br>
body{<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;overflow: hidden;<br>
}<br>
.scroll-div{<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;overflow-x: hidden;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;overflow-y: auto;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/* Rest of styling */<br>
}<br>

</p>
```

Ignore the code, everything you need is in the Run Code Snippet button.